# UITab freeze in iOS

Tags: objective-c, ios, uialertview, freeze, uitabcontroller

I am developing an iOS 5.1 application on Xcode 4.2.
I have a uitablcontroller with different tabs. My problem is when a tab is clicked , the application 'freezes' for few seconds and does all the codes it's meant to do, but it does not load the UIAlertView first as it should be.

I have the UIAlertView declared in the viewDidLoad.
Here is a code snippet:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{



NSLog(@"##### VIEW DID LOAD 1 #####");


// Display Alert: Loading

alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading"
                                       message:@"\n"
                                      delegate:self
                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                             otherButtonTitles:nil];

UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
spinner.center = CGPointMake(139.5, 75.5); // .5 so it doesn't blur
[alertView addSubview:spinner];
[spinner startAnimating];
[alertView show];

[super viewDidLoad];


NSLog(@"##### VIEW DID LOAD 2 #####");


self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;

[self callMainMethod];

}
```

When the tab is clicked, I can see that the first NSLog's are displayed in the Log, and then the main method is called, but the UIAlertview is not displayed.

Comment: Errata, I am using Xcode 4.5

Comment: Try calling the superview's `viewDidLoad` before your custom implementation.

Comment: ## Solution ## emrys57's answer solved the problem! The answer is to move the [self callMainMethod] to viewDidAppear. I had also needed to put [self.tableview reloadData] after calling the function as I needed to view the data on a Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `viewDidLoad` is running, it may be that the `frame` of the associated UIView has zero size. I don't know, but the `UIAlertView` may be trying to present itself in this zero-size frame. Does it make sense if you present the `UIAlertView` in `viewDidAppear`?

If `[self callMainMethod]` is taking lots of compute power, then the display might not be updated until it finishes. You could try moving it to `viewDidAppear`. You could also try delaying it, so that the main run loop for the UI thread, the thread that the display is updated on and the thread that executes`viewDidLoad` and all the other `view...` methods, has time to complete everything and become idle before you start the heavy processing. It's only when the run loop has done all the processing it can that it starts actually to update the display. Like this:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 200000000), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   [self callMainMethod];
}
```

The documentation for that is at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

If that suspicion is correct, you should then get the `UIAlertView` popping straight up, only to have everything go dead for a while, while `callMainMethod` executes.

I wish I knew how to write, "dispatch this block only after you've managed to finish updating the display with everything up to here", but I don't know how to do that. So the dispatch call above should delay the call to `callMainMethod` by 200ms, which is usually plenty.

If that works, you should probably start another question, something like "How can I stop the display freezing while I execute this method."

Comment: I tried adding the UIAlertView in the viewWillAppear as well as viewDidAppear, and it still 'freezes' when the tab is clicked, then displays the data and the alert. Thanks for your face response. I appreciate your help. =)

Comment: That's progress, at least. I updated the answer, and you could try that.

Comment: That was it!! Thanks alot!  Moving the mainMethod to the ViewDidAppear did solve the problem. Thanks alot for the very detailed and explanatory answer.

Comment: Jolly good! Pleased to be able to help. And thank you very much for the tick.